# c# write message to textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

Kind of new to c# GUI stuff

I am trying to output a message, a number to a textbox.

1 Button will calculate the number, then  I want to write a message like " Number has been seen: "

I tried

```
Form2.resultBox.Text.Write("Number one has been seen: ", num0);
```

that doesn't work.

Also tried

```
Form2.resultBox += Console.WriteLine("Numer one has been seen: ", num0);
```

Im going to have about 16 of these messages

ideas?

Comment: `resultBox.Text = "Number one has been seen: " + num0;` Read the error messages; you'll see helpful advice. (In particular, what *is* wrong.)

Answer (score 2):

```
Form2.resultBox.Text = "Number one has been seen: " + num0;
```

Answer (score 1):

To set the value of a TextBox, you should set a value on the Text property like so:

```
resultBox.Text = "Number one has been seen: " + num;
```

Answer (score 1):

how about using the string.Format

```
Form2.resultBox.Text = string.Format("Number one has been seen: {0}", num0);
```

eliminates having to use + sign

Comment: nothing wrong with + sign but in his case in my opinion it's better to pass params what if he wanted to have Nuber one has been seen: + num0 + Times..? wouldn't be easier to read {0}{1},num0,stringTimes for example..?

Comment: also think about in C# Immutable vs Mutable.. wouldn't it be better to use a StringBuilder to build Complex Strings vs using Operator overloading i.e string += some string(s) variable(s)

Comment: I agree with StringBuilder usage in that case, but I still prefer using + instead of {0}..

Comment: I'm not arguing with you on your preference Bojan but in the long run you will see that you will run into issues eventually when using operator overloading on complex strings .. you're approach is not incorrect.. I am just looking at best practices thats all.. cool..!